# distance between any two points in a metric space and its diameter

Tags: metric-spaces

Could anyone tell me how to prove the following?

$d(x,y)\le \text{diam }(S)^{1-\alpha}\cdot d(x,y)^{\alpha}$ where $S$ is any complete, separable metric space. Or compact metric space. $0<\alpha\le 1$?
Thanks for helping.

$\text{ diam }S=\sup\{d(x,y):x,y\in S\}$. thanks for helping to proceed.

$d(x,y)\le \text{diam} (S)$

Now, If $d(x,y)<1\Rightarrow (d(x,y))^{\alpha-1}>1\Rightarrow(d(x,y))\times \text{ diam }(S)$

Comment: $\iff d(x, y)\leq \text{diam}(S)$ but this is from definition of diameter. Holds for any kind of metric space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the definition of diameter,
$$
d(x, y) \leq \mbox{diam}(S).
$$
Raise both sides to the power $(1 - \alpha)$:
$$
d(x, y)^{1 - \alpha} \leq \mbox{diam}(S)^{1 - \alpha}.
$$
Now multiply both sides by
$$
d(x, y)^{\alpha}.
$$

Comment: is that result true for any metric space?

Comment: Yes.  I didn't use any special properties of the metric space, only the existence of a metric.